# Twitter not working on Motorola Xoom

Tags: android

I am developing an application for Android Tablet, which has Facebook and Twitter integration. All working fine in emulator as well as on Samsung Galaxy 7.1 inch device. But **Twitter** is not Working on **Motorola Xoom 3.2 Tablet device**. I am getting the following Toast Message.

***Authorization failed (server replied with a 401). This can happen if consumer key was not correct or signatures did not match***

Any idea??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using `Twitter4j`. I had a similar issue, and didn't find any solution. I somehow observed that if you are logged in inside the `Twitter App` from your phone, the Twitter authorization fails. If you don't have a `Twitter App` installed on your phone, the Twitter authorization will work. So I'm thinking somehow the keys that are retrieved by the `Twitter App` and your app, somehow get mixed up or something like this... maybe sombebody else knows more.

Good luck.